# Specify table column styling for Jekyll

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, markdown, jekyll

I'm using Jekyll to build a static web site using Bootstrap. I know how to specify style for a whole table (see below)

```
{: .table .table-striped}
| Name  | Roles | User ID |
| ----- | ----- | ------- | 
| Micky | CEO   | micky   |
| Tom   | CTO   | tom     |
```

But I don't found a way to specify style class for every column. I want to add class `col-md-4` for every column. How to make this happen?

Comment: In short, because there's no concept of a "column" in HTML. While rows are contained in `<tr>` elements, adding a class to every column would require adding it to the header cells… and the cells in the first row… and the second row… and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always revert to writing plain HTML in (between) your Markdown. The ultimate solution for everything without a solution.

Comment: Yes, I found some projects solve the problem in this way. So this will be one option for me.

Answer (score 1):

In short, Jekyll doesn't have a way to ad a class to a column because there's no concept of a "column" in HTML. While rows are contained in `<tr>` elements, adding a class to every column would require adding it to the header cells… and the cells in the first row… and the second row… and so on.

The simplest thing to do would be to tweak your stylesheet so that the cells in this particular table are as wide as `col-md-4`.

If you give this table a class of `md-4-table`, for instance, you could tweak your bootstrap CSS to say:

```
.col-md-4,
.md-4-table th, .md-4-table td,
... {
    /* whatever bootstrap actually puts in here */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I hope I don't have to modify `bootstrap.css`, this is too much tweaks than I expected. And I think we only need to specify style for the table header columns. The table body will follow the style as headers.

Comment: I just had a thought revolving around the `:nth-of-type` pseudo selector. I'll try to write it up shortly.